# How do I restart Kubuntu so settings take effect?

Tags: kubuntu, system-settings, restart

I'm trying Kubuntu for the first time, but my laptop's display is too high resolution to be able to read text, so I'm trying to rescale my display. So, I've set the scale in `Settings -> Displays -> Screen Scaling`. The dialog updates, and a message appears at the top of the dialog saying, ["Scaling changes will come into effect after restart"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPrTm.jpg).

The problem is that even after a restart, the changes aren't applied. In fact, when I go to the Screen Scaling dialog again after the restart, that message still appears at the top of the dialog as though the restart never happened.

I've tried changing the sessions setting so sessions aren't saved when logging out/shutting down, but that didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove these files to stop old session: `rm ~/.kde4/share/config/ksmserverrc`, and `rm -r ~/.kde4/share/config/session/*`

Comment: Thanks, but (sorry, I should have mentioned this before) I'm on KDE 5. I don't seem to have those files/directories. Instead I've got ~/.kde/... but neither the session directory nor ksmserverrc appear to be there... Do you have any idea where I could find them? Thank you!